# Reputation required to "create tags" vs. "retag questions"

Tags: discussion, reputation, retagging

On Stack Overflow , the [reputation required to gain the "retag questions" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) is less than the reputation required for the "create tags" privilege; on EL&U, it's the other way around.

What's the policy behind determining which privileged should require more reputation?

Comment: I don't think any normal user can answer this--we didn't program the site.

Comment: @simchona So we wait for moderators or some abnormal user to show up ;)

Comment: "Abnormal user", I like that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, and bear in mind that I am not sure, but I believe that the reason this is so is because Stack Overflow, given (1) its age and (2) its question volume, is much, much more likely than any other site to have all the tags it will need for some time. The only new ones that are likely to crop up are those of new technologies and those that are needed when tag cleanup occurs, and in both cases, a high rep user is likely to be involved. In contrast, SE 2.0 sites that graduated from Area 51 are smaller and newer than Stack Overflow and may not have all the niche tags that people might want to ask questions on, and so more people are allowed to create tags.

Comment: I agree; Stack Overflow is more restrictive in many ways. For example, on Stack Overflow suggested edits are approved by two users, while on other sites a single user can approve them; also, Stack Overflow requires users to have an account to ask questions, while on EL&U it is possible to ask questions without first create an account.